# Handling many requests in the same time

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table Users in MySQL includes 3 fields : ID (int), Name (varchar) and UpdateTime (TimeStamp). 
I have a java web application and one function to get one record in table Users, after that, check if UpdateTime is before current time ---> update UpdateTime by current time plus 2 hours.

And my problem is when having about 100 users access to my app and request to that function to get the same record in the same time, all of them will update UpdateTime. But I want only first user update UpdateTime, latecomers will only get data without update UpdateTime.

How I can do it? I really have no idea.

Thanks.

P/s: Sorry about my English, it seems to be not good :(

Comment: Look up [concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Sounds like a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: have you tried anything. or is it just a discussion before actual coding ??

Comment: After see comments, I tried add synchronized to my method, but I don't see anything changes.
I think in this case, when make 100 requests to this method, just only one do update, 99 another ones don't do it. But when I  try to do it with Jmeter, some of them do update (more than 1) and another ones do not.

Comment: You may want to look at MySQL's functionality for locking reads: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update time code should be in synchronised block.

Take write lock on your object and if someone has consumed lock before going on update operation and at the same time another request comes should get the pre loaded/after update data.

Chech synchronised keyword in java also check read write lock mechanism. This might help you.

following code might help you.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Test {
    boolean isWriteLockTaken;
    Map<Integer,String> cachedUsers = new HashMap<Integer,String>();  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            t.updateAndGetUser(1);
        }
    }

    public String updateAndGetUser(Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        if(isWriteLockTaken && !cachedUsers.containsKey(id)){
            this.wait();
        }

        if(!cachedUsers.containsKey(id)){
            isWriteLockTaken = true;
            synchronized(id){
                if(id==1){
                    // do processing to retrive user
                    System.out.println("Updating & loading user");
                    cachedUsers.put(id, "Gaurav");
                    return "Gaurav";
                }
            }
            isWriteLockTaken = false;
        }
        System.out.println("returning from cached list, not loading user details as it is already loaded");
        return cachedUsers.get(id);
    }

}
```

Thanks, 
Gaurav

Comment: After see comments, I tried add synchronized to my method, but I don't see anything changes.
I think in this case, when make 100 requests to this method, just only one do update, 99 another ones don't do it. But when I  try to do it with Jmeter, some of them do update (more than 1) and another ones do not.

Comment: I tried again and it worked, but I see a problem, when using synchronized for that function, the first request access to function and another ones must wait. So the last request will have to wait too long time to get data. If I only use synchronized for block of update time code, all of requests will get data in the same time and do update in turn. The thing I want is 100 requests access and get data int the same time, but just first one update.

Comment: As per initial answer you need to implement write lock, if any request has write lock then other request should be skipped and retrieved with old data

Comment: Added code in answer which might help you. If it works don't forget to vote up.. :)

Comment: Don't forget to notify thread otherwise it'll block execution. .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't know how to write lock in web app, because I think when initial new request, variables will be set default value.